# The example of creating Android application architecture design diagram

Tags: java, android, uml

I have developed the Android application, but my customer wants to get an application architecture design diagram, but I don't know how I can do it, which appplication I should use for it, etc. Is there any example of it or may be you know at least the program which is used for it? Thank you, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give him sequence diagrams for any important workflows and, probably, a class diagram for the 'big picture'.
I'm using ArgoUML http://argouml.tigris.org/ because it's free but you may want more professional tools.